# GNU Grub problem with boot into Windows 10 winload.exe

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, uefi, windows-10

Is my first time installing Ubuntu 16.04 and when i was installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 and i have Windows 10 with "UEFI" mode, my version of windows before this was the 7 i don't know why windows 8. When i put the boot mode in the BIOS to "UEFI & Legacy mode" the grub opens and when i select "Windows 8" it throws me an error telling me the

```
    winload.exe
```

isn't in the "/windows/system32/" i am searching on Internet and i don't found anything.

Comment: Sorry Enzo, but it's really unclear what you're asking here: Do you have a problem in Win10, Win8, Win7 or Ubuntu?

Comment: Well, if i put "only UEFI" on the boot mode in the BIOS i can access to Win10 but i wont enter in the Ubuntu grub at least i put again in the boot mode to "UEFI & Legacy", and the thing i want to do is enter to Windows 10 in the Grub, and when i launch the "Win8" because Ubuntu detects my OS as Win8 not Win10 after launching Win10 in Grub i got an error saying "/windows/system32/winload.exe" isn't there

Comment: You have to install both in UEFI mode then...

Comment: How i install Ubuntu in UEFI mode?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what actually happened to your PC, but it may help because when I got GNU grub error I used to use filling commands. May it may help you. I think you have windows 10 installed on you PC and you are using legacy mode, then follow these steps
1.Insert your bootable media of Windows 10(if Windows 10 installed else other)  and boot from it. 
2.When you will see the choose language box then press shift +F10 keys and you will see the command prompt opened. 
3.Then use these commands

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

If both commands made succefully then type exit and close everything. Remove your bootable MEDIA.And start your PC normally, and you will be happy. Hope this will work. Reply if worked or not.